# Inline Html Resizing smaller, creating bigger File size

Tags: html, image, optimization, resize

The problem I have is that I'm working with a CMS system Which is not originally designed by me. when I upload a product image to the cms at size 319x319 its size is around 13KB. The system is designed to cache the image and make a copy of it at 170x170, so it can be used elsewhere on the site, when i view that cached (smaller) image it remains at the same size, some on the website have even grown in size(memory that is).

Now i could only find one obscure reference with this happening in joomla, see link below
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=709&t=821407

I'm wondering whether there is a way to prevent this happening as a way of decreasing my overall page size, or am I looking completely in the wrong place?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagikmagick for image manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I'm looking for is reason behind why this occurring so i can change it, as i said this is someone else CMS system and i need to stop this happening, unfortunately image optimization wont help

Comment: Yes you can manupuliate the size or file size of the image when it is stored.

Comment: It would help if you show us some code and or the name of the cms

Comment: I dont have direct access to the code, I have to go through the designer to make changes like that, this is why its quite difficult, my assumption is that there is a way to specify how the image is handled, maybe using .htaccess but manipulating the file after its stored would work but is only a work around that duplicates work and not solve the problem

Comment: Well I meant to use the manipulation while the file is store there is really no other way than change the code